# How to access a two-dimensional Json (nested List) array without a key Flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart, nested

How to access a keyless two-dimensional array in flutter.

I want to access a two-dimension JSON array like this, and I can't access the array inside the other array that is nested, the second array has no key, with the key "data" I can reach the first array but inside that array there is another array and I can't access that one.

I want to show the same data in a Widge.

```
    [
      {
       "username": "gn",
        "data": [
         [
          "1 cap 1 libro 1",
          "2 cap 2 libro 1"
         ],
         [
          "1 cap 2 del libro 1",
          "2 cap 2 del libro 1"
         ],
         [
          "1 cap 3 del libro 1",
          "2 cap 3 del libro 1"
         ]
      ],
       "email": "Gana"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say, you save this array in a var named `data`.
Now, you can access all the elements like:

```
data[0]['data'] //this one is an array
data[0]['data'][0] //first array
//and change the index value for the remaining elements
```